# auto-starting new master

Tags: ros, master, roslauch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why does roslaunch auto-start a new master for every remote machine?

Things I've tried:
-playing w/ every variation of default tag for machines defined in the .launch

Things that work but extremely painful at our scale:
-hard coding ROS_MASTER_URI in the /opt/ros/fuerte/env.sh

I'm on the latest fuerte.

Cheers,
-Willy

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/149806/auto-starting-new-master/) by [uuilly](https://answers.ros.org/users/4356/uuilly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-04-07**:
I think this was a bug in roslaunch in Fuerte. I suggest upgrading to a newer version of ROS.

**Comment by [uuilly](https://answers.ros.org/users/4356/uuilly/) on 2014-04-07**:
Below you said that it was fixed. Is that not the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/36600/how-to-tell-remote-machines-not-to-start-separate-roscores-when-using-roslaunch-fuerte-regression/) this is fixed in ros-comm 1.8.14. Can yo confirm that you have that version or later of ros-comm ? ( `dpkg -l ros-fuerte-ros-comm` )

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [uuilly](https://answers.ros.org/users/4356/uuilly/) on 2014-04-07**:
Yup. Saw that thread. I'm up to date on all machines:

ii ros-fuerte-ros-comm 1.8.16-1precise-20130502-1635-+0000

Any other thoughts?